# Google API Data Transfer Insert: missing resource.applicationDataTransfer

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-admin-sdk

I'm creating simple PHP script for transfering ownerships of drive files between users in the same domain.  I want to use **Admin SDK Transfers** and **Insert** method.

Google has documentation about transfers [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/data-transfer/v1/reference/transfers)

I tried to transfer data through their webpage GUI and it went fine. What I can't do is how to make it work with PHP Client library.

Let's say I have prepared object for creating requests to Transfers resource

```
$transfers = new \Google_Service_DataTransfer($googleConnection);
```

googleConnection handles service account authorization so i can make requests like this:

```
$data = $this->transfers->transfers->listTransfers();
```

This returns data of all existing transfers in domain. Based on documentation and PHP Client library insert operation should work also.

```
$transferParams = new \Google_Service_DataTransfer_ApplicationTransferParam();
    $transferParams->setKey("PRIVACY_LEVEL"); //what kind of docs I want to transfer
    $transferParams->setValue(['SHARED', 'PRIVATE']);

    $appDataTransfer = new \Google_Service_DataTransfer_ApplicationDataTransfer();
    $appDataTransfer->setApplicationTransferParams($transferParams);

    $appDataTransfer->applicationId = "iDString";    //set application ID

    $newTransfer = New \Google_Service_DataTransfer_DataTransfer();

    $newTransfer->setOldOwnerUserId('accountID'); //origin account IDs are placeholders
    $newTransfer->setNewOwnerUserId('account2ID'); //destination account
    $newTransfer->setApplicationDataTransfers($appDataTransfer);

    $result = $this->transfers->transfers->insert($newTransfer); //execute insert
```

After executing insert I am getting code 400 with message Missing required field: [resource.applicationDataTransfer].

If I test real parameters via web they work. 
I must be missing something, because that exception doesn't make sense at all.

I'm also open to alternative solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setApplicationDataTransfers` method expects an array of `Google_Service_DataTransfer_DataTransfer` so you just need to update the following line (note the [] in the params)

```
$newTransfer->setApplicationDataTransfers([$appDataTransfer]);
```

Comment: Very nice catch. I was looking into sources of library and never found this was the reason. It works now, so thank you.